# Resizing images with imagemagick when they are larger than 10mb

Tags: shell, command-line, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to resize images larger than 10 mb.

This is my imagemagick commando:
`convert -strip -interlace Plane -resize 70% -quality 80% file.jpg file.jpg`

Can someone explain to me how i loop over the images in folder that are larger than 10mb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use find:

```
find /your/path/here -name '*.jpg' -size +10M -exec convert -strip -interlace Plane -resize 70% -quality 80% {} {} \;
```

This finds all files larger than 10 Megabytes and with names ending in `.jpg` and executes the command on them. `{}` is a placeholder for the name of the current file.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what i needed :)